# RegEx: 8-20 characters, but no spaces allowed

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to create a Regular Expression for a password field.

The requirements are 8 - 20 characters, but no spaces allowed.

I've tried `^[^-\s].{8,20}$` to no avail...

Comment: *Any* character except a space? i.e. UTF-8 characters are allowed?

Comment: Well no, not any... alpha numeric and typical special characters.

Comment: What do you define as "typical special characters?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the dot.

`^[^-\s]{8,20}$`

Comment: I'm still able to add a space at the end of the string ... I just don't want to allow any spaces at all.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It doesn't allow spaces at the end where I tested: http://regexr.com/3ano8

Comment: I'm able to add spaces at the beginning and the end of the input.

Comment: The anchors(^ at the start and $ at the end) prevent that. If it is allowing spaces at the start and end, it's somewhere else in your code. Can you show in your question how you're validating the input?

Comment: Sounds like someone is `$.trim`ing the input

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above that it should be alphanumeric with a few special characters, you would be best to allow characters rather than disallow them.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\*\!\\?\(\)]{8,20}$
```

On the other hand, if it's a password, you probably should allow the whole UTF-8 character set (including spaces) and allow a lot more than 20 characters.

Comment: I'd like it to allow for ! at least ... and no spaces at the end.

Comment: So the last character can be a space, but not the rest of the password?

Comment: No, no spaces at all. I'm still able to add spaces at the beginning or the end of the input using your regex.

Comment: Not possible. The `^` means 'the beginning of the string'. Everything inside the `[` ... `]` brackets means allow any of these characters (and space is **not** in those brackets). The `{` ... `}` brackets means allow between 0 and 20 times. The `$` means 'this is the end of the string'. Nowhere in there does it allow for a space. If your code says there's a space, there's a problem with your code.

Comment: Are you testing from the browser? Probably your browser (or perhaps the framework you're using) is trimming the value to remove any spaces at the beginning or end. Check what value is actually being passed to the regex. Even better, test your regex with PHPUnit so you **know** it's doing what you expect. You don't want to mess up passwords.